# How to implement socket.io server with echo server in Golang

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io

I want to initialize echo server

```
app := echo.New()
app.POST("/register", handlers.Register)
app.Start(":5000")
```

then implement socket.io server in the same port.

I tried to do double servers but it doesn't looks useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example from the [repo](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io)

- https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/blob/master/_examples/go-echo/main.go

Comment: yes that's what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

Follow the echo documentation and you can find a cookbook that implements a socket endpoint in the same port of the api.

https://echo.labstack.com/docs/cookbook/web

```golang
app := echo.New()
app.POST("/register", handlers.Register)
app.GET("/ws", handlers.MyWsHandler)
app.Start(":5000")
```

Comment: Yes I see it but implementing socket.io in the project make it easier specially when it comes to front end parts